# Python regex search for all matching strings

Tags: python, regex, csv, parsing

I have an issue that might be simpler than I'm making it.

```
   # /usr/bin/env python
   import csv
   import re
   import math

   gt_user = raw_input("Enter person you want to look for")
   for list, nums in info:
     if gt_usr == list:
        re.search(r'/.$/', get_usr)
        total += numbs
```

I need to find all strings matching user input names ex: User inputs EXAMPLE but in the csv data set there are EXAMPLE-2455 I need to look for all of them and and combine them together into the same data set since they are from the same place. ex: customer and customer-2334 are the same person.

Comment: You'll be much better off just using `.startswith()` for this case.

Comment: So you're getting the numbers and adding them?

Comment: `^EXAMPLE.*$` if you really want to use regex. Obviously `EXAMPLE` would be a variable

Comment: I'm getting data from a .csv and i have to look for strings that match what i put above to make sure i collect everything that matches.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "match." Does that always mean "starts with?" Or does it mean "contains?"

Comment: I'm sorry i meant "contains" a certain suffix in the string.

Comment: Assuming case sensitivity isn't a problem, just use the `in` operator then. no need to overkill with regex

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include an example of what your CSV looks like, how you're parsing it, and what is in `info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've omitted the parsing of the CSV into `info`, which represents a list of rows, where each row contains a pair of items: a name and some number you want to total. It sounds like you want something like the following:

```
total = 0
gt_user = raw_input("Enter person you want to look for")
for name, num in info:
    if gt_user in name:
        total += num
```

Or more simply:

```
gt_user = raw_input("Enter person you want to look for")
total = sum(num for name, num in info if gt_user in name)
```

Comment: Damn n00b mistakes      in      works at the  if loop part